# Unable to access vm guest running apache using macvtap behind router

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, libvirt

**Setup**

Host OS is Centos7 running libvirt.  I have multiple guests running using macvtap as an interface to a bridged bonded interface (br0).  br0 is a bridge of bond0, which includes two ethernet interfaces em1 and em2.  I have a Cisco RSV4000 between the local network and the WAN.  Port 80 is being forwarded to my guest IP (static) running apache web server.

`Internet <==WAN==> Cisco RSV4000 <==LAN==> CentOS7 VM[<==macvtap0==>Guest OS]`

**Problem**

I can access the webs server on the LAN but am unable to access it from outside our network.  If I try to access the web server from an outside network I receive `(52) Empty reply from server`.

(Note: This seems to be true for all my guests, as one of them is a VPN server, and I am unable to connect from the WAN side).

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I replaced the Cisco RSV4000 with a Ubiquiti USG Pro 4 and all is working.  The problem is reproducible by switching back to the RSV4000.  Not sure what is causing this phenomena.